# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController predicate for enabling selection of the contact with predicateForEnablingPerson

Tags: ios, objective-c, abpeoplepickerview

I have an `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` as below

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
```

I need to disable some of the contacts being selected from the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController's list view.

While browsing, got some idea like this

```
// Predicate to enable only the contacts having a mail id atleast.
picker.predicateForEnablingPerson = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"emailAddresses.@count > 0"];
```

So I implemented a predicate like below to exclude the selection of contact with the first name I have.

```
NSString *firstName = @"Kate";

// Predicate to disable selection of the contacts with the first name given.
    picker.predicateForEnablingPerson = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName != %@",firstName];
```

Unfortunately its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found the list of the constants that you can use in the predicate in ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.h

```
// Constants to use in predicates:
// A LabeledValue has a 'label' property and a 'value' property.
// A PhoneNumber has a 'stringValue' property, a 'countryCode' property, a 'formattedStringValue' property and a 'normalizedStringValue' property
// A InstantMessageAddress has a 'username' property and a 'service' property
// A SocialProfile has a 'username' property and a 'service' property
// A PostalAddress has a 'street' property, a 'subLocality' property, a 'city' property, a 'subAdministrativeArea' property, a 'state' property, a 'postalCode' property, a 'country' property and a 'ISOCountryCode' property
//
extern NSString * const ABPersonNamePrefixProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);               // "namePrefix"                 NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonGivenNameProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);                // "givenName"                  NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonMiddleNameProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);               // "middleName"                 NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonFamilyNameProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);               // "familyName"                 NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonNameSuffixProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);               // "nameSuffix"                 NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonPreviousFamilyNameProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);       // "previousFamilyName"         NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonNicknameProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);                 // "nickname"                   NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonPhoneticGivenNameProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);        // "phoneticGivenName"          NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonPhoneticMiddleNameProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);       // "phoneticMiddleName"         NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonPhoneticFamilyNameProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);       // "phoneticFamilyName"         NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonOrganizationNameProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);         // "organizationName"           NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonDepartmentNameProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // "departmentName"             NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonJobTitleProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);                 // "jobTitle"                   NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonBirthdayProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);                 // "birthday"                   NSDateComponents
extern NSString * const ABPersonNoteProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);                     // "note"                       NSString
extern NSString * const ABPersonPhoneNumbersProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);             // "phoneNumbers"               array of LabeledValue with PhoneNumber values
extern NSString * const ABPersonEmailAddressesProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // "emailAddresses"             array of LabeledValue with NSString values
extern NSString * const ABPersonUrlAddressesProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);             // "urlAddresses"               array of LabeledValue with NSString values
extern NSString * const ABPersonDatesProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);                    // "dates"                      array of LabeledValue with NSDateComponents values
extern NSString * const ABPersonInstantMessageAddressesProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);  // "instantMessageAddresses"    array of LabeledValue with InstantMessageAddress values
extern NSString * const ABPersonRelatedNamesProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);             // "relatedNames"               array of LabeledValue with NSString values
extern NSString * const ABPersonSocialProfilesProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // "socialProfiles"             array of LabeledValue with SocialProfile values
extern NSString * const ABPersonPostalAddressesProperty NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);          // "postalAddresses"            array of LabeledValue with PostalAddress values
```